# Dynamically changing coloration of TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have Windows 8 application and trying to create landing view for it. It's still needs to spupport Windows 8, so Hub control is unavailable. But it looks similar. First section will contain darker picture and second one will contain GridView like elements on almost white background. And during scrolling application title should stay in place.

But as a result I have a problem with title TextBlock. While it's placed over an image it should be white, but after scrolling further it should invert color of the text part over white background.

Here is a sample markup:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="500" Fill="Purple"/>
            <Rectangle Width="5000" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="LightCyan"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TextBlock Text="Application Name" Foreground="White"
               FontSize="32" FontFamily="Segoe UI" 
               FontWeight="Bold" Margin="48 24 0 0" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Maybe someone has ideas on how it should be implemented?

Comment: I think your approach is unintuitive, for readability nothing should be under your text block, i.e. use two rows in your grid, the first with Height="Auto" will contain the text, the other with Height="*" will contain your scroll viewer.

Comment: It's one of the requirements that title should be placed over the picture and stay in place during scrolling.

Comment: Actually in the solution I gave you the text has its own line but there seems to be a reasonable approach in doing it the way you asked, see this : http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34771/whats-a-good-way-to-use-text-over-a-picture

Comment: Sadly, but I'm not the one specifying UX for an application. And in our case picture alway will be toned down to almost on color. So white title over the picture looks pretty good. But then I have this problem with scrolling over another part with white background.

Comment: You could use a stroke when drawing your text but YMMV, other than that get in the touch with the UX designer about the issue, he should be well aware of such issues, he's a designer after all. I see no better approaches to your issue than with the two different solutions I just gave you, i.e. there's no solution that will magically work for all cases unless you accept some compromises.

Comment: To clarify question:
There are two columns in a view - first one dark, second - light. In top left corner there are title, which stays in place while view is scrolling. Text should be white on while over dark part and became black over light content. So it should change it's color gradually while scrolling. This scenario is often encountered in different places. Just I don't know how to implement it in XAML.

Comment: Are you trying to make it static where you could use the scrollviewer vertical offset to maybe determine when to change its color? Or trying to make it reactive to whatever the image below it is color wise? The first way would be much easier.